# Can't login with apache HttpClient 4.5.1

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to login to a website on which I want to download and parse the HTML page right after the login. For testing I'm using the following JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testLogin() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
    CloseableHttpResponse loginResponse = null;
    CloseableHttpResponse getDataResponse = null;

    try {
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        RequestConfig globalConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
                .build();

        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        context.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

        httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig)
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                .build();

        List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<>();
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "username"));
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "password"));
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "Login"));
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("logintype", "login"));
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", "1"));
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_url", ""));
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tx_felogin_pil[noredirect]", "0"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams);

        HttpPost login = new HttpPost("https://localhost/");
        login.setEntity(entity);

        loginResponse = httpClient.execute(login, context);

        List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
        loginResponse.getEntity().writeTo(System.out);

        HttpGet getData = new HttpGet("https://localhost/");
        getDataResponse = httpClient.execute(getData, context);

        getDataResponse.getEntity().writeTo(System.out);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (loginResponse != null) {
            loginResponse.close();
        }
        if (getDataResponse != null) {
            getDataResponse.close();
        }
        if (httpClient != null) {
            httpClient.close();
        }
    }
```

After executing the login request there are the needed sessions in the CookieStore but the entity of the response still contains the HTML of the login page. The problem remains after executing the getData request. Still the login page content in the HttpResponse entity.

With the following curl command it is working:

```
curl --data "user=username&pass=password" https://localhost/
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Might need to use [HttpPost](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) instead of HttpGet

Comment: I do a POST to send the credentials to login and to get the session id's and afterwards a GET to download the content. A POST instead of a GET couldn't be solution.